# How to add some padding between QPushButton’s boundary and its inner text?

Tags: qt

Longer strings don’t look too good in a QPushButton, because there’s no spacing between the text and button’s frame, i. e. the text is placed tightly within the button. Is there a way to add some padding?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the padding of a `QPushButton` via its stylesheet.

```
myButton->setStyleSheet("padding: 3px;");
```

Or

```
myButton->setStyleSheet("padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 3px;"
"padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;");
```

More information on stylesheets can be found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/stylesheet-reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do this in Qt Designer?

Comment: Right-click on your button in the Designer and try 'Change styleSheet...' ;-)

Comment: Also you would change border and margin, to get the effect https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#

Answer (score 7):

Rather than having to set a stylesheet for each button, I found it easier to update the sytle so that the minimum size for each button is a little bigger. You can subclass QProxyStyle which is the easiest way to modify styles, since it will apply changes to whatever style is selected ie QWindowsXPStyle, QWindowsVistaStyle, QMacStyle etc.

Override `sizeFromContents` like this to make the minimum size of buttons a little bigger:

```
class ProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    QSize sizeFromContents(ContentsType ct, const QStyleOption* opt, const QSize & csz, const QWidget* widget = 0) const
    {
        QSize sz = QProxyStyle::sizeFromContents(ct, opt, csz, widget);
        if (ct == CT_PushButton)
            sz.rwidth() += 20;

        return sz;
    }
};
```

And then after you create your application, but before you create your first window call:

```
a.setStyle(new ProxyStyle);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the padding for all buttons in a window/widget with:

```
QPushButton { padding: 10px; }
```

Much better than applying to each subwidget.

Comment: Much better indeed!